# Need the latest date from 2 columns in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

As a part of my project, I need to display the latest date of the the two columns in the third column in oracle table. If dates are same, it should display latest based on the time. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

E.g.1:

```
col1                 col2                col3
12-FEB-17 03:24:23   15-FEB-17 08:12:52  15-FEB-17 08:12:52
```

It should display the col2 data in col3 as it is 3 days latest than col1.

E.g.2:

```
col1                col2               col3
02-FEB-17 03:01:57  02-FEB-17 03:01:59 02-FEB-17 03:01:59
```

It should display the col2 data in col3 as it is 2 secs latest than col1.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the GREATEST() function. For example:

```
with test as
( select to_date( '12-FEB-2017 03:24:23','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) col1,
         to_date( '15-FEB-2017 08:12:52','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) col2 from dual union all
  select to_date( '02-FEB-2017 03:01:57','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) ,
         to_date( '02-FEB-2017 03:01:59','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) from dual 
)
select col1, col2, greatest( col1, col2 ) col3
from test


COL1                 COL2                 COL3
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
12-FEB-2017 03:24:23 15-FEB-2017 08:12:52 15-FEB-2017 08:12:52
02-FEB-2017 03:01:57 02-FEB-2017 03:01:59 02-FEB-2017 03:01:59
```

Comment: Thanks Bob. This works. I did mistake in using the to_date function previously. Now it is perfect. Thanks a lot..

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you find something on what to do when someone answers you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `greatest` but with `NVL`. Without NVL, if you have `null`s then `null` will be the output of `greatest`

```
select col1,col2,
greatest(
    nvl(col1,to_date('1901-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')),
    nvl(col2,to_date('1901-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
        ) as col3
from your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

I really dislike using made up dates, because what if both are null? You would get 1901-01-01. Better yet, use COALESCE to return the non-null value:

```
WITH your_table
     AS (SELECT 'COL1 Greater' test, SYSDATE col1, SYSDATE - 10 col2
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'COL2 Greater', SYSDATE col1, SYSDATE + 10 col2
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'COL1 null', NULL, SYSDATE col2
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Both null', NULL, NULL
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT test
     , TO_CHAR (col1, 'YYYY.MM.DD') col1
     , TO_CHAR (col2, 'YYYY.MM.DD') col2
     , TO_CHAR (GREATEST (COALESCE (col1, col2), COALESCE (col2, col1)), 'YYYY.MM.DD') AS col3
  FROM your_table;


TEST         COL1       COL2       COL3      
------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
COL1 Greater 2017.03.01 2017.02.19 2017.03.01
COL2 Greater 2017.03.01 2017.03.11 2017.03.11
COL1 null               2017.03.01 2017.03.01
Both null
```